# Estimating correlation between variables

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a set of questions and a set of students. Each student gives an answer to a subset of the questions. An answer is either correct or wrong.

My objective is to compute the expected score distribution for subsets of questions that have never been asked together.

Using the ratio of correct answers for each question, I define a probability of success for each question. However, it's actually wrong to assume that the probability of success of the questions are independent:

- Let A and B be the events "good answer for question" qA and qB. If qA and qB are really close, not only their success rate will be close but $P(B | A) \approx 1$
- Even if the questions are less close, $P(B | A) \ge P(B) \text{ and } P(B | \text{not} A) \le P(B)$
- If I introduce a third question qC, the $P(C | A \text{ and } B)$ is also bigger than $P(C | A)$ and $P(C | B)$.

If I ignore that correlation between the probabilities, the result is that I have very few really bad students, and few great students.

How can I quantify the correlation between the questions? What can I do to take it into consideration in my calculus? There are several hundreds questions but a subset of question is only between 5 to 30 questions. I'd be happy with an approximation if that saves me computation time.